# PHPExcel Orphan/Widow, getRowDimension

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am having an issue with saving a PDF file from PHPExcel and it creating widow/orphans with my data.

I know of the function to create page breaks,

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setBreak( 'A10' , PHPExcel_Worksheet::BREAK_ROW );
```

but I would like to know if there is a function to know the current height of a range of cells.

I have found references to "getRowDimension" in functions like

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension('10')->setRowHeight(100);
```

but I cannot find any documentation on that function. Does anyone know if it can calculate the height of the chosen row and/or take a range of rows?

Also, is there a function to calculate the usable space between the header and footer of each page? Or should I calculate that from the page margin?

Thank you,
Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getRowDimension('10')
    ->getRowHeight();
```

Will return the row height for the specified row. This is the height in "points", where 1 point is the equivalent of about 1/72 of an inch (or about 0.35mm). A value of `0` indicates a hidden row; while a value of `-1` is the default value, which is 12.75pt (about 1/6 of an inch).

The `PHPExcel_Shared_Drawing` class contains a number of functions for converting between points and other units of measure, such as `pointsToPixels()` and `pixelsToPoints()`, and `pixelsToEMU()` and `EMUToPixels()` (English Metric Units).

The whole issue of Microsoft's units of measure is really a confusing minefield, but there's a useful [blog post here](https://startbigthinksmall.wordpress.com/2010/01/04/points-inches-and-emus-measuring-units-in-office-open-xml/) discussing the different units of measure use in MS Office